# Is it possible to add UserAgent to YQL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I'm using [cross-domain-ajax](https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) in which, YQL is being used.
It has this line in it:

```
query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';
```

so I added **user-agent** to it like this below:

```
query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*" and ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.1; ja-jp; Galaxy Nexus Build/ITL41D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"';
```

Now it won't return the value any more :(
My main javascript is this:

```
url = 'http://foofoofoofoofoofoo.com';
var content ='';
$.get(url, function(data){
  content = data.responseText;    
});
```

How can I add user-agent to YQL?
The reason why I want to do it is because the content of HTML sources differ depending on which user-agent is being used with.

I want the HTML source when it's being accessed with smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that this is not possible (at *least* for *non-HTML* data).

According to the [YQL reference](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/provider/), YQL accesses *'non-HTML'* data under User-Agent `Yahoo Pipes 2.0` (that is css, xml *and even robots.txt!*).
Note that it doesn't care for the 'robots.txt' rules as it isn't a crawler.
Therefore, when accessing *'HTML-Data'* and the robots.txt check prevents `Yahoo Pipes 2.0` from accessing your content, it will then fetch the target page using a different user agent:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14`

As workaround you could set up your own proxy in between using PHP, you'd have a look at [curl_setopt CURLOPT_USERAGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) (making yahoo hosted YQL query your proxy instead) OR install version of YQL on your server (making it your hosted YQL AND modify the API to handle your UA parameter).