# Cross-domain requests don't work with YouTube

Tags: javascript, ajax, yql

Why does the following YQL request not work?

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "https://www.youtube.com" AND xpath = "*";
```

([permalink](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%22%20AND%20xpath%20%3D%20%22*%22%3B))

It works as expected with http://google.com ([permalink](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%20AND%20xpath%20%3D%20%22*%22%3B)), for example. What's wrong then?

I need to make cross-domain request to youtube via AJAX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work for me, it responds with the correct "this browser is not supported" page, presumably because the console doesn't report as a valid web browser.

Comment: @Kevin B It seems that it works from time to time. Try to do the same request now -- it doesn't work for me at the moment

Comment: @Kevin B It works again. Is it possible to change User-Agent for YQL then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345092/is-it-possible-to-add-useragent-to-yql

Comment: @Kevin B Yeah, I already saw this question but I don't really understand it tbh. It looks like I request HTML data, so what should I do then? How can I add User-Agent in this case?

Comment: it doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: @Kevin B Accoding to the answer, "It appears to me that this is not possible (at least for non-HTML data)". I thought that the part "at least for non-HTML data" suggest that it can be done for HTML data

Comment: Do more research on the topic, i don't know the answer. One solution that will absolutely work would be you building your own ajax proxy to do it the way you need.

Comment: The url you are requesting from in your question in fact works, and has never failed for me, it just doesn't necessarily return anything useful due to the useragent being used. I have found no documentation that suggests you could change the useragent, thus making it impossible to solve this using YQL unless there's some documentation i haven't found or some hidden feature. Have you considered using the api instead?